# Backup Folder with files but leave behind empty files/folders

Tags: windows, backup, file-transfer, duplicate

I see this asked in linux and ubuntu forums/sites but could never find one for xcopy or Windows x86/64 platform (or an application)

I wish to back-up a folder to another drive, but I would like to "keep" the files and folders on the source drive BUT sized at 0 bytes.

I want to save disk-space by backing up the data/files, but I want to make sure that I know what I have so I don't accidentally make duplicates. (also an easy way to know what you have on the Back-up drive instead of having to plug it in everytime)

Hopefully my question makes sense, First time asking on SU (1st time ever asking any where, google failed me, or my search term was too vague)

Windows 7 Ult. x64

Comment: Have you tried Robocopy (built in to Vista+) robocopy /mov should move the files, but leave directories intact. Note /move is different than /mov

Comment: everywhere I look says /mov moves files and folders AND deletes source

Comment: Is there some reason for not using more standard tools to do your backups?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "standard"
But my "Backup" implies that I'm taking a file/folder (mostly .rar's) copying it to an external drive for means of stroage, but retain an empty(0 zero byte) file on the source drive so I know I already have that file/folder on an External Drive.

Comment: Just going off `robocopy /?` here:

"  /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
 /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying)."

Comment: The thing is, I do NOT want to delete source files & folders
(unless I'm reading it wrong)
I wouldd like to keep the names of files and folder structure to prevent duplicating files and folders I may have on my External Drive.
Would like to clarify that I'm not manually addins files/folders to this location its an automated process where it adds files to this location, but I'm running out of space on the drive and it makes no sense to move the save location to a new folder as the program doesnt log what files I ALREADY have.

Comment: The program auto-cancels downloads/moves if I already have a file/folder with the same name.
I'm just trying to reduce duplicates so I don't need to go in later to run an anti-duplication software with my ExtHDD plugged in.